# Selected SVN connector library is not available

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-kepler

When trying to connect to my team's svn repo, I'm getting this error.

> SVN: '0x0040010b: Obtain Project Name' operation finished with error: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
>
> If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
>
> If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
> Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.

There are quite a few pages on this exact problem that reference this

http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/update-site/

as the solution. However, I am unable to load this page (for the past 40+ hrs). Can anyone either confirm or deny it's status?

Answer (score 7):

The update site for Kepler seems to http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/kepler-site/

Comment: To anyone still having this issue, the website where you can get the most current update sites is https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/products/svn/subversive/download